# Remove items in a List of int arrays depending a condition C# Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Having a List of int arrays in C# like:

```
            List<int[]>  arrList = new List<int[]>();
            arrList.Add(new int[18] { 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 153, 135, 117, 99, 81, 63, 45, 26, 25 });
            arrList.Add(new int[4] { 183, 209, 210, 184 });
            arrList.Add(new int[4] { 184, 210, 211, 185 });
            arrList.Add(new int[4] { 185, 211, 212, 186 });
            arrList.Add(new int[4] { 186, 212, 213, 187 });
            arrList.Add(new int[4] { 187, 213, 214, 188 });
            arrList.Add(new int[4] { 188, 214, 215, 189 });
            arrList.Add(new int[4] { 189, 215, 216, 190 });
            arrList.Add(new int[4] { 190, 216, 217, 191 });
            arrList.Add(new int[13] { 192, 191, 217, 234, 251, 268, 285, 302, 319, 349, 350, 351, 193 });
            arrList.Add(new int[17] { 194, 193, 192, 191, 217, 234, 251, 268, 285, 302, 319, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 195 });
            arrList.Add(new int[21] { 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 217, 234, 251, 268, 285, 302, 319, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 197 });
            arrList.Add(new int[23] { 197, 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 217, 234, 251, 268, 285, 302, 319, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 198 });
```

I want to remove the elements of item in List that are already in other item on the same List, however these items do not have same length, so **I want to keep the longest one**

How to keep this item

```
arrList.Add(new int[23]{197,196,195,194,193,192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,198});
```

and delete following items from same List?

```
arrList.Add(new int[13]{192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,193});
arrList.Add(new int[17]{194,193,192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,352,353,195});
arrList.Add(new int[21]{196,195,194,193,192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,197});
```

The issue is the items to be removed are "contained" in the item I want to keep, for instance

```
        {196,195,194,193,192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,197}
                {194,193,192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,352,353,195}
                        {192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,193}
    {197,196,195,194,193,192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,198});
```

However the items to be removed share a common pattern, their last element is first before they are repeated on item I want to keep

## edit

One Way I came up is:

1. get first item then compare it against all items
2. if the item is "contained" on item save its index on a List
3. Loop List that has those items and then remove the items from original List

However Is there a function "contains" I can use?

other idea I came up is :

1. Create alternate List that is almost a copy of original but their last element is put first

for example item

```
{196,195,194,193,192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,197}
```

would become

```
{197,196,195,194,193,192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,352,353,354,355}
```

2. Then compare every item in alternate List with original List

for instance:
 I would be able to compare item I want to delete

```
{197,196,195,194,193,192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,352,353,354,355}
```

with item I want to keep

```
{197,196,195,194,193,192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,198}
```

Comment: `What would be the best way to keep item` What are the ways you have tried?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear... Seems, you want to delete items, which all elements already exist in other items. Ami right?

Comment: yes exactly, the `elements of item in List` are already in `other item on List`, but they do not have same length, I want to keep the longest one

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it, but not too much efficient is:

```
var list = arrList.Where(l1 => arrList.All(l2 => l1 == l2 || l1.Except(l2).Any()));
```

Here, you filter arrays that are subset of another in `arrList`. You can check for subsets using `!l1.Except(l2).Any()`, so you will keeps arrays that aren't subsets of any others.

In your case, `list` will have the arrays of lengths `4`, `18` and `23`.

---

If elements in each array are unique, you can project each array to a `HashSet` and use `IsSubsetOf` (takes *O(n+m)* in worst case), to increase the performance you can sort the arrays according to its `Length` and check each array with others that are latter in the list:

```
var hashSets = arrList.Select(l => new HashSet<int>(l))
                      .OrderBy(hs => hs.Count)
                      .ToArray();

var result = new List<HashSet<int>>();

for (int i = 0; i < hashSets.Length; i++)
{
    bool isSubset = false;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < hashSets.Length; j++)
        if (hashSets[i].IsSubsetOf(hashSets[j]))
        {
            isSubset = true;
            break;
        }

    if (!isSubset)
        result.Add(hashSets[i]);
}
```

If you need the sets as arrays you can project back each `HashSet<int>` to `int[]`.

Comment: Excellent Linq solution! Much, much simpler than mine (in my head)!

Comment: One last question is, What would happen if I have longest item `{197,196,195,194,193,192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,198}` and then other item that is almost a subset (i.e. it has elements but some more) for instance subset `{192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,351,193}` must be removed but `{192,191,217,234,251,268,285,302,319,349,350,87,88,89}` not, if you check the difference is on last items `351,193`

Comment: @cMinor: I do not quite understand what you're asking, in this case the longest array and `{... 88, 89}` is kept and `{... 351, 193}` is removed as you said. This is what you want or you want to filter `{... 88, 89}` too?

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep items that are almost (of 10 elements 6 are part of subset but 4 dont, then i want to keep) I jus t want to remove exact subsets (of 10 elements 10 are same as other item in list)

Comment: @cMinor, a linq solution provided by Arturo does exactly what you want. Have you found issue with that?

Comment: @cMinor: That's exactly what these solutions do, only filter exact subsets.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to check if a list contains another list

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

var containsList1 = list2.Intersect(list1).Count() == list1.Count;
```

and if so delete list1

Comment: And how would it be if I compare the same list againts itself?

Comment: I think, you're on wrong track. Please, read OP's requirements careflly.